# Find child element's index in the HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the actual index (in the HTML markup) where a child of a element is located.

Say I have the following markup:

```
<p id="foo">Lorem <i>ipsum</i> d<strong>ol</strong>ar</p>
```

And the following code:

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
var children = $foo.children();
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    console.log(children[i]);
}
```

This outputs the elements `<i>ipsum</i>` and `<strong>ol</strong>`. Is there any way to calculate that these elements start at the HTML index 6 and 20 of the parent element `#foo`? I would like to avoid using a REGEX approach based on the `tagName` of the element, but that is the only solution I've come up with this far.

Are there any solutions/APIs that I've overlooked that can solve this without overcomplicating things too much? I'd like to make this as generic as possible, with the support of nested tags too, where e.g. `#foo > i` is the base element and I look inside it to see if there are any nested tags there.

It is also kind of tricky to Google this as most questions/answers deals with actual position, and not the position in the HTML markup.

Working example:

```js
var $foo = $('#foo');

var startIndex = 0;
var children = $foo.children();
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
 console.log($foo.html());
 console.log('<' + $(children[i]).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase());
 var this_index = $foo.html().substr(startIndex).indexOf('<' + $(children[i]).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase());
 console.log(startIndex + this_index);
 console.log('----');

 // Update startIndex (to avoid returning the first occurence if multiple children of same type)
 startIndex = this_index;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="foo">Lorem <i>ipsum</i> d<strong>ol</strong>ar</p>
```

Output:

```
Lorem <i>ipsum</i> d<strong>ol</strong>ar
<i
6
----
Lorem <i>ipsum</i> d<strong>ol</strong>ar
<strong
20
----
```

However, this is a rather ugly solution and is based on string matching. Is there any way of doing this search/match based on the child element instead? That would limit the possibility that the markup is invalid (for example capitalized HTML tag).

Comment: "most questions/answers deals with actual position, and not the position in the HTML markup".  Im not sure I follow, can you explain the difference?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I dont want to know the relative position (200px, 100px etc), and I don't want to know that `<i>ipsum</i>` is the first child of `#foo` and `<strong>ol</strong>`. I want to know where in the HTML markup of `#foo` that these objects are located/starts. Where are the `<` that opens the tags of these children.

Comment: So what's the expected output in this case?

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn: 5 and 19, as written above. I'll post a working example

Comment: Ok, what you want is the element's `index` in the parent's children. But for what purpose, what is the end game here? so we have context.

Comment: @DelightedD0D I want to create animated translation of my CV there a cursor replaces letter-by-letter the original language with the next language. Problem is that if it just replaced the HTML char by char it will corrupt the markup if there are any children in the elements. Thus, by using this approach I can create a sub-cursor that jumps inside the child element and continues to remove content there, when the element is empty the element is removed and the cursor continues to remove from the base element again.

Comment: Could you not simply manipulate the entire html as a string?  `$foo.html()`   The text position in the DOM can easily be changed by adding whitespace with no affect on the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$foo.html().indexOf(children[i].outerHTML)` should work

Comment: That did indeed work. In combination with a substring to avoid the (very unlikely) scenario that two elements are identical, it works like a charm. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `indexOf` on the string containing inner html of the parent node and search for string containing outer html of the child node:

```js
var haystack = document.querySelector('#foo');
var needle = haystack.querySelector('i');
var startIndex = haystack.innerHTML.indexOf(needle.outerHTML);
var endIndex = startIndex + needle.outerHTML.length;

document.writeln('start: ' + startIndex + '<br> end: ' + endIndex);
```

```html
<p id="foo">Lorem <i>ipsum</i> d<strong>ol</strong>ar</p>
```

Similarly it also works if you replace `i` with `strong` and yields `start: 20` `end:39`